# Use of @AttributeOverride

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate3

My Embeddable class is like below.

```
`@Embeddable
public class AddressBean {
    private String streetAddress;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String cityName;
    private String stateName;
    private String zipCode;
}`
```

And  Embedded attributes are

```
@Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="streetAddress", column=@Column(name="APPLALTSTREETADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address1", column=@Column(name="APPLALTADDRESS1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address2", column=@Column(name="APPLALTADDRESS2")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="cityName", column=@Column(name="APPLALTCITYADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="stateName", column=@Column(name="APPLALTSTATEADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="zipCode", column=@Column(name="APPLALTSTATEZIP"))
    })
    private AddressBean altAddress;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="streetAddress", column=@Column(name="APPLSTREETADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address1", column=@Column(name="APPLADDRESS1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address2", column=@Column(name="APPLADDRESS2")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="cityName", column=@Column(name="APPLCITYADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="stateName", column=@Column(name="APPLSTATEADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="zipCode", column=@Column(name="APPLSTATEZIP"))
    })
    private AddressBean applAddress;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="streetAddress", column=@Column(name="APPLALTDIRECTION1ADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address1", column=@Column(name="APPLESIGNADDRESS1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address2", column=@Column(name="APPLESIGNADDRESS2")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="cityName", column=@Column(name="APPLESIGNCITYADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="stateName", column=@Column(name="APPLESIGNSTATEADDRESS")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="zipCode", column=@Column(name="APPLESIGNSTATEZIP"))
    })
    private AddressBean esignAddress;
```

I want to store streetAddress for altAddress and applAddress but not for esignAddress.
It means, From the above code, I need to modify statement

```
`@AttributeOverride(name="streetAddress", column=@Column(name="APPLALTDIRECTION1ADDRESS")),`
```

Please help me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking us how to delete text in your editor?  What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: In the above code, it inserts all 6 attributes for 3 objects in the DB(when using session.save() method). That is the default mechanism. But I don't want streetAddress to be stored for esignAddress(which is APPLALTDIRECTION1ADDRESS in the code). If I remove streetAddress AttributeOverride statement above esignAddress, It  will be stored as streetAddress column in the DB

Comment: Split `AddressBean` into two embeddables, i.e. `StreetAddressBean` and `DefaultAddressBean`

Comment: @wypieprz thanks.. didn't notice that